# Get URL value in static page in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing, ejs

I am beginner to node and express. In my current application the page is displaying using this code :

```
var app = express();
app.use(serveStatic('static', {'index': ['index.html']}));
```

and in static folder, there are there files:

> css, index and a js file

Listening to 3000 port it is working normally.

But what if I want to access URL like this :

> localhost:3000/name=someName

I want to use this name parameter in my js file which is available in static folder.
or suggest any other routing method to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the query parameters in your .js file it can be done. So the code would look like this:

**Server (index.js)**

```
"use strict";

var express = require("express");
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = express();
app.use(serveStatic('static', {'index': ['index.html']}));

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Static express server started");
```

**HTML (/static/index.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
    <body onLoad="readParameters()">
        <div>
            <h3 id="1" >Loading..</h3>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

**Client side JavaScript (/static/test.js)**

```
var readParameters = function()
{
    console.log('Getting parameters..');
    let params = (new URL(location)).searchParams;
    console.log('Query parameters: ', params.toString());

    var html = 'Query parameters: ';
    for (let p of params) {
      html += "<br/>" + p.toString();
    }

    $("#1").html(html);
}
```

Then you can test by entering:

```
http://localhost:3000/?test=value
```

Into your browser.

You should see:

```
Query parameters: test=value
```

on the index page.

The code tree should look like this:

```
root
¦   index.js
¦
+---static
        index.html
        test.js
```

3 Files:

```
/index.js (Node server side code)
/static/index.html (HTML)
/static/test.js (Test JavaScript file)
```

Comment: WoW!! great answer with full explanation. it worked. but I'm getting output **test=value** but i want value only. then i try `localhost:3000/?value` and i got  **value=** (an extra = sign)

Comment: That should be easy, the params object is a fully querable object you can do: params.get('test') to get your parameter. You can also enumerate by doing for (let p of params) { .. }. I'll update my answer!

Comment: and why you define express code in index.html. I am not understanding this

Comment: Sorry... My mistake, I cccidentally put some server code in the HTML..I'll update the answer!!

Comment: yes, okay. node and express are awesome thats why I'm learning these. I am inspired from programmers like you who are always ready to help. cheers!!

Comment: No problem @JagdeepSingh, they are very cool, the best thing about them is you get a solution running with 90% less code than with Java, C# etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can defined route like below,

```
router.get('/name=:id', function(req, res, next) {res.render('index', { title: req.params.id});});
```

Route parameters are named URL segments that are used to capture the values specified at their position in the URL. This captured values we can access with 'req.params' object. for reference  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: How do i use this in my case. my index file is in static folder. I am completely beginner.

Comment: In your case you need to define route url as '/name=:id'. Then you can access any parameter you have given using 'req.params.id'. try to access this url 'localhost:3000/name=someName' then you will get value of 'req.params.id' as 'someName'